# Regex: Remove number in brackets at end of line in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

When I run my code :

```
$SearchClass = "allreportstd"
$URI = "https://MySite/Default.aspx"

$WebRequest = Invoke-Webrequest -URI $URI -UseDefaultCredentials
$WebRequest.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName($SearchClass) | % {Write-Host $_.innerText}
```

This produces the following output:

**Workstations: Unsupported Win 10 editions (1803) (0)

Workstations: Unsupported Win 10 editions (1809 and earlier) (3)

Workstations: Unsupported Win 10 editions (1903) (7)

Workstations: Unsupported Win 2000 (0)

Workstations: Unsupported Win XP (1)

Workstations: Windows 10 editions (3775)**

How to remove the last parentheses at the end of the line ?

- *Workstations: Windows 10 editions (3775)* becomes *Workstations: Windows 10 editions*
- *Workstations: Unsupported Win 10 editions (1809 and earlier) (3)* becomes *Workstations: Unsupported Win 10 editions (1809 and earlier)*

Thanks a lot for your help ..

Comment: Try `$_.innerText -replace '\s+\(\d+\)$'`

Comment: I know this says RegEx, but I couldn't help myself: `$_.InnerText.SubString(0, $_.InnerText.LastIndexOf('(') -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$_.innerText -replace '\s*\([^()]*\)$'
```

The `\s*\([^()]*\)$` regex matches zero or more whitespaces, then a `(`, then any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` at the end of string.

Note that it will not replace the `(...)` string that is followed with trailing whitespaces. To also consider those, you will need

```
$_.innerText -replace '\s*\([^()]*\)\s*$'
```

`\s*$` matches zero or more whitespace chars at the end of string.

See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs*%5C%28%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%5C%29%5Cs*%24&i=Workstations%3A%20Unsupported%20Win%2010%20editions%20%281803%29%20%280%29%0D%0AWorkstations%3A%20Unsupported%20Win%2010%20editions%20%281809%20and%20earlier%29%20%283%29%0D%0AWorkstations%3A%20Unsupported%20Win%2010%20editions%20%281903%29%20%287%29%0D%0AWorkstations%3A%20Unsupported%20Win%202000%20%280%29%0D%0AWorkstations%3A%20Unsupported%20Win%20XP%20%281%29%0D%0AWorkstations%3A%20Windows%2010%20editions%20%283775%29&r=&o=m).

If you need to remove *nested, balanced parentheses at the end of string*, you can use

```
$_.innerText -replace '\s*\((?>[^()]+|(?<x>)\(|(?<-x>)\))*(?(x)(?!))\)\s*$'
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs*%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Cx%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-x%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28x%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%5Cs*%24&i=Workstations%3A%20Unsupported%20Win%2010%20editions%20%281803%29%20%280%29%0D%0AWorkstations%3A%20Unsupported%20Win%2010%20editions%20%281903%29%20%287%20%28description%29%29&r=&o=m). The `(?>[^()]+|(?<x>)\(|(?<-x>)\))*(?(x)(?!))` part matches balanced round brackets.